# Processing multiple rows in an hive udf

Tags: hive, hive-udf

How could I take many rows inside an hive-udf? I need an entire column `name` inside the function so that it could be added to an ArrayList inside UDF. The following is the column name:

```
Name
jhon
jone 
mike
```

I want to take all of the names in the column inside the UDF.

Comment: collect_set() and collect_list()  return array

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for aggregating function.

First, check if there is any existing aggregation functions that could suite your needs - [Built-in Aggregate Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)).

If there are none, you have to create custom UDAF, which requires you to:

- write your own evaluator and resolver (see this tutorial - [Custom UDAF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GenericUDAFCaseStudy)),
- compile them,
- add binaries to hive classpath,
- register function in hive with `CREATE FUNCTION` ([Create Function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateFunction)).